# How to instantiate a variable of forall in a hypothesis in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have two hypotheses

```
IHl: forall (lr : list nat) (d x : nat), d = x \/ In x l' -> (something else)
Head : d = x
```

I want to `apply IHl` on `Head` as it satisfies `d = x \/ In x l` of IHl. I tried `apply with` tactic which fails with a simple hint `Error: Unable to unify`.

Which tactic should I use to instantiate variables in a hypothesis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your hypothesis `IHl` takes 4 arguments: `lr : list nat`, `d : nat`, `x : nat`, and `_ : d = x \/ In x l'`.

Your hypothesis `Head : d = x` does not have the proper type to be passed as the 4th argument. You need to turn it from a proof of equality into a proof of a disjunction. Fortunately, you can use:

```
or_introl
     : forall A B : Prop, A -> A \/ B
```

which is one of the two constructors of the `or` type.

Now you might have to pass explicitly the `B` Prop, unless it can be figured out in the context by unification.

Here are things that should work:

```
(* To keep IHl but use its result, given lr : list nat *)
pose proof (IHl lr _ _ (or_introl Head)).

(* To transform IHl into its result, given lr : list nat *)
specialize (IHl lr _ _ (or_introl Head)).
```

There's probably an `apply` you can use, but depending on what is implicit/inferred for you, it's hard for me to tell you which one it is.

Comment: Both of them work. Thanks! The `pose` one will leave IHl intact and place a new hypothesis while `specialize` will directly work on IHl and replace it with the result.